# Working with text files encoded as Windows-1250 and UTF-8

Tags: command-line, bash, windows, encoding

I am switching between Ubuntu and Windows frequently therefore I have some encoding problems with text files.

If I save text file in Ubuntu, everything works fine in both systems.
But Ubuntu doesn't discover encoding of files saved with Windows. Every time I open the "windows file" in Ubuntu text editor I have to change encoding options.

Solution is changing encoding from Windows-1250 to utf-8.

So the question is how to open each file with Windows-1250 and save it with utf-8, for every file in sub-directories of current directory (recursively I mean). Can I do it in terminal or I need some external application.

I'm looking forward for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I prefer to use `recode` for this. It's not installed by default, but available through the package by the same name. It also changes CRLF line endings to LF.

```
sudo apt-get install recode
recode cp1250.. file.txt
```

You can do this for all txt files in an entire dir

```
recode cp1250.. ./*.txt
```

And recursively by combining with `find`

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec recode cp1250.. {} +
```

The standard option is to use the `iconv` command, which is installed by default, but this does not change the line endings, so you need to do that in another step:

```
iconv -f cp1250 < file.txt | sed $'s/\r$//' > newfile.txt
```

In the long run, I'd recommend changing your windows editor's default character set and line ending to UTF-8 and UNIX line endings (LF,`\n`) to avoid having to do the conversion after the fact.

---

**CR** means **Carriage Return** (`\r`)
**LF** means **Line feed** (`\n`)

Windows uses both, but unix-like systems uses only **LF**.

Comment: Very good solution, thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text makes saving to different file encoding pretty easy. You can also reopen with different encoding and work with multiple files, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35797635/5806210.) for more details.

Comment: it would be nice if you could expand your answer here with the details so we don't have to go to the other post to achieve the desired effect